How to get the name of the requesting virtual host
I live in Germany and have a website hosted by IONOS. IONOS anonymizes all IP addresses in the server log files for data protection reasons. The host-id is always 0.
That's why I have my own script for generating a log file for certain files that logs the complete IP addresses of the requesting servers.
I use this code in PHP:
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$host = gethostbyaddr($ip);

Now my question:
Is there a way to find out what the name of a virtual host is if several different websites are hosted under one IP address as part of name-based virtual hosting?
I tried to use the info of the HTTP request header, but there is only the name of my virtual host under the host section.
$headers =  getallheaders(); 
foreach($headers as $key=>$val){
    $gah .= $key . ': ' . $val . " ";
}


In a nutshell: no. If the requester doesn't voluntarily put that piece of information into the request, no.

There is no such thing as a virtual host for the client. Only for the HTTP server, you have a "Host" header to allow webservers to implement vhosts (i.e. to allow one server with one IP to handle multiple websites).
